# Comment/Uncomment lines based on variable - R

Tags: r, if-statement, comments

Having an R code like this:

```
for (i in 1:length(DV)){names(DV[[i]])<-paste("DV", substr(names(P2[[1+10*(i-1)]]),12,19), sep="_")}
for (i in 1:length(DW)){names(DW[[i]])<-paste("DW", substr(names(P2[[1+10*(i-1)]]), 12,19), sep="_")}
```

How to automatically comment/uncomment these lines based on a variable. I want to re-run the code several times and for each iteration it should include (or not) some lines of the code. For example:

```
var<-TRUE

if (var) then {comment/uncomment lines 39:43}
```

Comment: Your example is the only thing which comes to mind.  In enterprise software, you will often see certain code which is only intended to run in debug mode.  The usual way of handling this is to just wrap that code in an `if` statement based on some global flag (`var` as you wrote above).

Comment: Quick reminder that you do not need the `(var == TRUE)` if `var` is `logical`. `if(var)` is enough when `var` takes boolean values.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I guess the `if` approach is correct but I am missing then the function, command, etc. to perform the commnet/uncomment task in R

Comment: If you're looking to physically comment out regions in your code, then I think you would need a separate script on top of the script you actually want to run.  And I'm not sure if it would be worth the effect to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Frequently a feature like this is implemented via a configuration file that is read when the script is executed, along with `if()` statements rather than comment blocks. We can simulate this with file read as a `textConnection()`. We will then use `assign()` to assign the logical value to an object, and use it to control the execution of subsequent code blocks.

```
# read config file and use it to process data
# 
rawData <- "environment,parameter,value
dev,debug,TRUE
test,debug,TRUE
prod,debug,FALSE
"

configParms <- read.csv(textConnection(rawData),header=TRUE)
# assign the value from the data frame for DEV environment to an object 
assign("debugOn",configParms[configParms$environment =="dev" & 
                             configParms$parameter == "debug","value"])

debugOn

if(debugOn){
     # execute this code block
     message("Entered debug code block")
}
message("passed debug code block")
```

...and the output:

```
> debugOn
[1] TRUE
> if(debugOn){
+      # execute this code block
+      message("Entered debug code block")
+ }
Entered debug code block
> message("passed debug code block")
passed debug code block
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although @Len Greski answer is much more technical and I am sure it's a more professional approach, I just figure it out how to resolve my problem in an easy way.

Instead of commnet/uncomment the lines to avoid (or not) them to be run, I used the `if` statment.

```
var<-TRUE

if (var) {
for (i in 1:length(DV)){names(DV[[i]])<-paste("DV", substr(names(P2[[1+10*(i-1)]]),12,19), sep="_")}
for (i in 1:length(DW)){names(DW[[i]])<-paste("DW", substr(names(P2[[1+10*(i-1)]]), 12,19), sep="_")}
}
```

That's all. If `TRUE` it will be done, if `FALSE` it will not.